# Using both styled-components ThemeProvider and React-Navigation in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, themes, styled-components

I'm trying to create themes for my React Native app using styled-components. However, when I attempt to access values from my theme in a styled component, I get an error saying

> **"Property 'primary' does not exist on type 'DefaultTheme'."**

Here's an example of my styled component:

```
const StyledText = styled.Text`
  font-size: 50px;
  color: ${(props) => props.theme.primary};
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
`;
```

The color is set correctly in my app, but VS Code throws an error there.
I'm using React Navigation for routing in my app, and because it provides its own theming system, I have issues with my VS Code.

Here's how I'm setting up my app:

```
function App() {
  const currentTheme: ITheme = lightTheme;

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={currentTheme}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name='Home' component={HomeScreen} options={{headerShown: false}} />
          <Stack.Screen name='CreateRoute' component={CreateRouteScreen} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

This is how I keep my theme:

```
export enum Themes {
  light,
  dark
}

export interface ITheme {
    primary: string,
    primary_dark: string,
    background: string,
    text: string,
    text_accent: string,
    input: string
}

export const lightTheme : ITheme = {
    primary: '#079A4B',
    primary_dark: '#115B33',
    background: '#FFFFFF',
    text: '#1E1E1E',
    text_accent: '#747683',
    input: '#F4F4F4'
};
```